# GTK+ / GTKMM Signal on "changed" on a textbuffer does not receive data

Tags: gtk, gtkmm

On the same window, I have 20 text views and I need to handle in only one callback the "changed" signal coming from the text buffers under them.

What is the best way to implement this? I mean, how to retrieve the text view widget concerned by the text change ?

I tried to pass the text view widget object itself on connect for the signal "changed" but it is not working. I also tried the same kind of implementation for buttons and it works perfectly for the "clicked" signal.   Why isn't it working for text views with underlying text buffers?

The code for connect:

```c
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(WidgetSecret))), "changed", G_CALLBACK(on_SecretText_changed), WidgetSecret);
```

and the callback:

```c
void on_SecretText_changed(GtkWidget *p)<
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to make it work. First is to conform to Gtkmm only, and not to mix up Gtk and Gtkmm:

```cpp
Gtk::TextView* pSecret[21];
```

Then, retrieve all objects from Glade:

```cpp
for (int i=1; i<=20; i++) {
    sprintf(Bidon, "tvCh%0d", i);
    pBuilder->get_widget(Bidon, pSecret[i]);
}
```

Finally, use `sigc::bind` to transmit an integer:

```cpp
int id = 1; // this is the Id to pass to callback for this TextView

pSecret[id]->get_buffer()->signal_changed().connect(sigc::bind<int>(sigc::ptr_fun(&on_SecretText_changed), id));
```

with the following callback:

```cpp
void on_SecretText_changed(int id)
{
    // id is retrieved and used here
}
```

Comment: Please make sure to mark this as solved!